# The PM2's status is online but the service is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, service, pm2

As the title, I use PM2 with Nodejs. The PM2's status is `Online` but sometimes my Nodejs's service is not working.
If I restart the PM2 or run my service by the command line: it's fine.
I read my PM2's log but it's empty. Can someone help me understand this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem after changing my pm2 command to use ecosystem.config.js the problem solved. I think interpreter change from /bash/sh to node has fixed my problem. (or may be exec_mode from fork to cluster)